# Django tables - Column relation to populate data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I have these models.

```
class Domains(models.Model):
    '''Domain listing for ISO'''
    domain_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    domain_title = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_id
#sample data output would be 
id      title
A5      A5 title
A6      A6 title

class SubDomain(models.Model):
    '''Sub-domain listing for ISO. Relationship with Domain'''
    domain_key = models.ForeignKey(Domains, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subDomain_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subDomain_title = models.TextField()
    subDomain_objective = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subDomain_id
#sample data output would be 
id      title            objective
A5.1    A5.1 title       A5.1 objective
A6.1    A6.1 title       A6.1 objective
```

My views currently are simple queries that use objects.all or objects.filter to store the list in a variable. This view is not complete but i am just testing at this point. That variable is then looped in my template tags as so:

```
table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub domain Title</th>
            <th>Sub domain objective</th>
        </tr>

    {% for record in a6titles %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan=1>A6</td>
        <td>{{ record.subDomain_id }}</td>
        <td>titles: {{ record }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Now, as you can imagine. When the table populates. The domain Id loops and populates its results. Same with the sub domains.

How do I generate the table such that it looks at the domain Id. Sees A5 and then only populates the subdomain A5.1 (ID, title and objective) in its respective columns. Then it sees A6 and so on.

I am thinking of two options. 
1. I create a function in my views with if/else and output that to a dictionary. 
2. I use something like djangotables2. I don't want a learn something new as I am still grasping basic Django principles.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get `Domain` as colspan header befor each `SubDomain` set?

`domains = Domains.objects.all()`

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr>
        <th>Sub Domain ID</th>
        <th>Sub domain Title</th>
        <th>Sub domain objective</th>
    </tr>
    {% for domain in domains %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3>{{ domain.domain_id }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% for sub_domain in domain.subdomain_set.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ sub_domain.subDomain_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ sub_domain.subDomain_title }}</td>
                <td>{{ sub_domain.subDomain_objective }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Great - I am getting closer. Now it puts all the results in the domain id column of the table. To simplify, I am just pulling the domain id and subdomain id for now.

        {% for domain in domains %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan=1>{{ domain.domain_id }}</td>
             </tr>
            {% for sub_domain in domain.subdomain_set.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ sub_domain.subDomain_id }}</td>  
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.